# How to change backgroundcolor of HTML element by using input from HTML form using JS EventListener

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I'm fairly new to JS and i'm having trouble changing the background of a HTML element by using input from a HTML form and event listeners. This is what i've tried so far:

HTML:

```
<div class="item" id="taskThreeContainer">
<h2>Task 3</h2>
<p>When writing a valid CSS background color in the input below, the background of this item should change to that color.</p>
<input type="text" id="task3Input">
<script src="script.js" async defer></script>
```

JS:

```
//Task 3
const inputColor = document.getElementById("task3Input").value;
const taskThreeContainer = document.getElementById("taskThreeContainer");

function convertColor() {
    taskThreeContainer.style.backgroundColor = inputColor;
};

document.getElementById("task3Input").addEventListener("input", convertColor);
```

Any help would be much appreciated

**Solution (JS):**

```
//Task 3
const taskThreeContainer = document.getElementById("taskThreeContainer");

function convertColor() {
    const inputColor = document.getElementById("task3Input").value.toString();
    taskThreeContainer.style.backgroundColor = inputColor;
};

document.getElementById("task3Input").addEventListener("input", convertColor);
```

Comment: You tried to read the input value, before it even had one. Accessing the value belongs _inside_ of your inout handler function.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you, this worked! I solved it by moving the taskThreeContainer to the input handler function convertColor :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, you need to read the value, being actual / valid at the time You want to apply it to style:

```html
<script >
  const inputColor = () => document.getElementById("task3Input").value.toString();
const taskThreeContainer  = () => document.getElementById("taskThreeContainer");

function convertColor() {
 
  console.log(inputColor())
  taskThreeContainer().style.backgroundColor = `${inputColor()}`;
};

document.getElementById("task3Input").addEventListener("blur", convertColor);

</script>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/0U8s8a4NUciwTgGt?open=lib%2Fscript.js

Answer (score 1):

```js
function getColor() {
  let color = document.forms["colorForm"]["color"].value;
  documen.getElementById("changeable_element").style.color = color;
}
```

```html
<div id="changable_element">Something...</div>
<form name="colorForm" onsumit="getColor()">
<input type="text" name="color"/>
<input type="submit" name="Submit"/>
</form>
```

You will need to make something like this. It's also recommened to check the input if its a valid color.